# How to put border colour to every element on android automation like UI Automator using java, selenium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver

I am automating sample for testing android UI.  I want to highlight with red color of currently executing element border same like as UI Automator.

How to achieve this using following languages java, selenium and android driver?

I have used following code, but its produced following error =>

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack trace information)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementid').focus();");
```

Below approach also not working.

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

My expectation is to highlight every element its like a button, label, text box, drop down and link anything.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to make it is to just set some conspicuous `css` style to your element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@someAttribute='someValue']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript('arguments[0].style="border-style: solid; border-color: red"; background-color: yellow;', element);
```

This will set yellow background to element + red border line (you can set different parameters)

**Note**

The significant drawback of this approach is that you actually change visual appearance of web-element (till page refresh or redirection) and it will be quite difficult to remove this "highlight", so it can be used if you need no more actions on current page

Comment: I think this ll work on web application. I need same functionality on android driver.

Comment: You mean you want `selenium` to work with `Android` UI? Or with web-browser on `Android` device?

Comment: Yes. Please help am struggling almost a day.

Comment: `selenium` allow you to handle browser automatically just like real user do... You cannot use `selenium` to handle `Android` applications or something else. You could use `UI Automator` for this purpose that you've already mentioned

Comment: Selenium with Android Device on custom application not web browser. Please help am struggling almost a day.

Comment: You cannot use `Selenium` with `Android` custom applications!

Comment: Is other any way to highlight?. I mean using any open source tools.

Comment: If you don't want to use `UI Automator`, try `Robotium` https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium. There are few more http://bitbar.com/top-5-android-testing-frameworks-with-examples/